# What is the potential risk with this code?

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a distinct counter to detect if all tasks that is added to the `ThreadPool` has completed and want to use it as a barrier. So, when a function that is added to the `ThreadPool` is completed, `workDone` will be called, and count will be decreased. The main thread will be locked by calling `waitForALL()` method until the count is cleared to `0`. Is this implementation reasonable and what risk does it have from the concurrency perspective?

I am still using .net 3.5, code has been updated as below.

```
public class BarrierCount
{
    private static volatile BarrierCount INSTANCE = new BarrierCount();
    private int count = 0;
    private static volatile Object o = new Object();

    public static BarrierCount getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private BarrierCount() { }
    public void increaseCount()
    {
        lock (o)
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    public void workDone()
    {
        lock (o)
        {
            count = count - 1;
        }
    }

    public void WaitForAll()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            lock (o)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Thread.SpinWait(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're reinventing the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) class.

Comment: FYI - there is a [codereview.se] Stack Exchange site that you might get better answers on. You could flag your question to be migrated there (click the "flag" link and choose other, and type that you would like your question to be migrated to CodeReview.SE).

Comment: Can't use CountdownEvent as I am using .net 3.5

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6790730/2266486

Comment: Don't change the question Code like that to incorporate answers. Makes the answers look wrong. Best to add another code block and say that it incorporates advise from answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

OP has since updated question so this answer makes no sense any more WRT question asked!! Those edits have also been lost in migration from stack overflow it seems.

Purely from a concurrency perspective and not commenting on if the design is fit for purpose:

---

## Newly added Volatile

You do not understand this, I am not going to go into why, just read up on stack overflow/MSDN or don't use it. As I remember you had a `readonly` on the instance. That was correct.

In general don't `lock(this)`, because (although not in this case... yet) `this` can also be locked from external code (`lock(BarrierCount.getInstance())`), and that allows deadlocks to occur. Although no deadlock is possible here as the methods are guaranteed to return.

Instead add a specific lock object:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();
```

---

### Note

`readonly` not `volatile`. `readonly` makes it clear to readers/modifiers that the reference is safe to use from multiple threads. It also stops modifiers from changing the reference (unless they remove the `readonly`, but they should make them think twice at least).

In `WaitForAll` you read `count` without a lock. Suggest you add a private `GetCount()` which locks.

I'm not sure how this is used, the `setCount` is presumably called once before the work commences. If the tasks have started and there is **any** risk in them calling `workDone` before `setCount` then it won't ever reach zero.

I would loose `setCount` in favour of an `IncrementCount()` method called before starting each task.

---

## But

You should look at [Task.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) before you do more on this.

Comment: I am still using .net 3.5

Comment: @Helic 1. If you want to do concurrent programming, I would strongly suggest you to consider upgrading. .Net 4.0 makes many things much easier. 2. [There is a port of TPL for .Net 3.5.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2987473/41071)

Comment: @svick - I'm sure arbitrary reason `x` is stopping them.

Comment: 3.5 does not stop you using Task. There is a Microsoft back port on nuget.

Comment: @weston yes, Volatile is wrong here. But is readonly necessary, as it is defined as static and private, this code should be executed at only once and no inheritance access is allowed to this variable.

Comment: No, it's not nessassary, it's more of a defensive programming approach. Letting others or future you know that you must not overwrite the reference.

Comment: `readonly` also lets you (or others reading the code) know it is a thread safe reference.

Comment: @weston I made another change here
    private volatile int count = 0; 
and in the WaitForAll method, instead of using a lock, I simply use 
    if (count == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
I think it should guarentee to see the latest count value. Is it correct use of Volatile?

Comment: I believe so, though you must still lock in some way when incrementing and decrementing, either by lock or by `Interlocked.Increment\Decrement` as mentioned in other answer.

Comment: @weston, yes true, But to assign a value to count, no lock is needed. Thanks

Comment: Ok as long as you understand a++ or equivalent is not valid, volatile or not.

Comment: Alternatively, if the number of tasks is <= 64, you can use [WaitHandle.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6(v=vs.110).aspx).  It has been around since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you stick with your approach, you can get rid of the lock entirely by using InterlockedIncrement/Decrement on the counter. Reading an `int` is atomic in C# so the spinning doesn't need locking (if Interlocked* is used to increment/decrement).
2. Why is this a singleton? There is no reason for that and it's likely to make unit testing code which uses it a pain. Just create a barrier object and pass it to all tasks which need to by synchronized on it. Makes it more reusable as well. What if you have two groups of tasks which need to be synchronized independently?
3. An approach which would get rid of the spinning is to use an event (although this require locking again)

   ```
   public class BarrierCount
   {
       private int _Count = 0;
       private readonly object _BarrierLock= new object();
       private readonly ManualResetEvent _BarrierIsOpen = new ManualReset(true); // barrier is open by default

       public void Enter()
       {
           lock (_BarrierLock)
           {
               ThrowIfCountIsNotSane();
               _BarrierIsOpen.Reset(); // close the barrier
               _Count++;
           }
       }

       public void Leave()
       {
           lock (_BarrierLock)
           {
               _Count--;
               ThrowIfCountIsNotSane();
               if (_Count == 0) 
                   _BarrierIsOpen.Set(); // open barrier again
           }
       }

       public void Wait()
       {
           _BarrierIsOpen.WaitOne();
       }

       private void ThrowIfCountIsNotSane()
       {
           if (_Count < 0)
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Barrier count below 0. Called Leave more often than Enter?");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone suggested upgrading to TPL is definitely a good choice. 
Also since the constraint of .net 3.5 explore **async methods through Delegates**, that already has a **WaitAll** method on the **IAsyncHandle** 's. Check that out..

Here.. I am going to recommend usage of `Interlocked.Increment & Interlocked.Decrement` (it's available in .net 3.5) wherever you are incrementing or decrementing the counter. 
`Interlocked` is helper class provided in library to handle atomic increment and decrements. It handles overflow condition. The code will be more neat. 
More read here -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx

Also it will be a good option to expose the `count` as property to let know other classes how many is left.

```
public class BarrierCount
{
    private static volatile BarrierCount INSTANCE = new BarrierCount();
    private int count = 0;
    private static volatile Object o = new Object();

    public static BarrierCount getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private BarrierCount() 
    {

    }

    public int Count //updated
    {
        get
        {
            return count;
        }
    }

    public void increaseCount()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count); //updated
    }

    public void workDone()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref count); //updated
    }


    public void WaitForAll()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (o)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Thread.SpinWait(100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can lose the lock entirely. It provides no value. Reading an `int` is guaranteed to be atomic in C#.

Comment: you mean in _WaitForAll_ method?